# Как в backbone предстваление вставить другое предстваление?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Я не очень хорошо знаю Backbone, поэтому вопрос.

Мое приложение генерит таблицу и уменя есть два представления для этого

1. Для строчек `<tr>` `App.View.BaseRow`
2. Для тела `<tbody>` таблицы  `App.View.BaseTableBody`

При нажатии на одну из строк таблицы, должно происходит следующее:

1. Ниже той строки на которую было произведено нажатие вставить
   новую строку.
2. В новую строку вставить некоторые данные, причем модель этих данных должна будет отличаться от модели данных `App.View.BaseRow`, если быть конкретней то там должна появится другая таблица с другими столбцами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как это реализовать в стиле Backbone.JS ?

Comment: Сделайте `View` для `<tbody>`, И `Collection` для строк. Из `View` слушайте клик по строке, меняйте `Collection` и вызывайте `this.render()`

Comment: Да это у меня есть конечно. и с рендерингом основной таблицы проблем нет но вот как мне интегрировать в таблицу новую строку в определенном месте вот это для меня загадка.....

Comment: Найдите индекс модели, по которой кликнули и добавьте новую модель в коллекцию `Rows.add(new Row(), { at: index + 1 })` (как-то так, точно не помню)

Comment: ок спасибо, то есть это сработает даже в том случае если коллекция основана на модели отличной от той которую я хочу интегрировать внутрь вставляемой строки?